# Wireless not working toshiba satellite c640

Tags: wireless, atheros

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. It's a dual boot system. Wirelss working absolutely fine on Windows 7. But in Ubuntu it says

> Wireless is disabled by hardware switch

But there is not switch for wifi in my laptop.

I have tried these solutions

1. rfkill unblock all
2. blacklist acer-wmi

Interesting part is wifi is working fine if I use a live CD. Network card in my laptop is AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)

This problem is driving me crazy.

Comment: what you get when you type this in terminal: `ifconfig -a`

Answer (score 1):

Same problem to yours on Toshiba Pro C640. 
In my case, I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 x64 then disabled Wifi, then installed Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and finally got "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch". Cannot re-enable wifi on new OS.

Then my working solution:

- prepare a USB disk boot or CD ... with ubuntu 10.04 x64
- boot an run ubuntu on USB/CD
- then try `rfkill unblock all`
- verify by `rfkill list`

Sorry to author of this idea, I don't remember the link to add a ref here.

You may need to boot in Windows 7 again just to enable wireless (like my Ubuntu 10.04 x64).

Comment: If 10.04 can unblock it but 12.04 cannot, this indicates a bug in 12.04, which [should be reported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).